# Nifi sensitive info inside custom properties

Tags: apache-nifi

*How secure is to put database crenetials inside [Nifi custom properties](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.2.0/building-a-dataflow/content/referencing-custom-properties-via-nifi-properties.html)? Is that less secure comparing to Parameter Context?*

For example, DBCPConnectionPool processor has sensitive property called 'Password'. If I'll set custom property as 'Password', *will it be possible to find unencrypted password value in data provenance or variable registry?*

### UPD

Thanks to @BryanBende, it's clear that I can't put credentials into `.properties` files because variable files aren't encrypted with `encrypt-config.sh`.

In other hand, I still don't understand how single Nifi Registry commit may be reused between DEV and PROD environments automatically switching to required Parameter Context. Moreover, Parameter Context switch requires disabling of all Controller Services, which is pretty painfull and complex with Nifi REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sensitive parameters are stored encrypted in flow.xml.gz, and so are any values of properties where the property descriptor has `sensitive(true)`, like the Password property of DBCPConnectionPool.

I'm not fully sure what the definition of "Custom Property" is for this question, but if you mean dynamic properties added to a component by clicking the + icon in the top right of the config screen, then the answer is that it depends... each component decides what the descriptor looks like for a custom property, so if the descriptor says its sensitive then it is encrypted, if not then its not.

Example, in DBCPConnectionPool, dynamic properties are not sensitive:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-dbcp-service-bundle/nifi-dbcp-service/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/dbcp/DBCPConnectionPool.java#L307-L316

If you are referring to using flow file attributes to obtain values in expression language, then those are not currently encrypted. So if you had a flow file being passed around with a "db.password" attribute, that value would not be fully protected in all places.

If you are talking about variables, they do not support any sensitive storage / encryption, which is one reason why parameter contexts were created.

Comment: sorry for vague definition of custop properties. By custom properties I meant `dev.properties` or `prod.properties` files included by specifying `nifi.variable.registry.properties` at `nifi.properties`.

Comment: Are custom properties safe in this context?

Comment: I would say no because there is no way to store encrypted values in the files located at 'nifi.variable.registry.properties'

Comment: There is also no way to restrict who can use these values in niif, any user who has access to the UI can create a component and enter ${db.password}  into a field that support expression language, and if db.password was in the variable properties file, now they are able to use it

Comment: but isn't it the same for lets say Parameter Context? Any user that has access to UI can use values of Parameter Context. Shall we protect ourselves from re-using variables/parameters? Or shall we protect from copy-pasting those variables from Nifi to other places?

Comment: `prod.properties` file is located in file system and should be read only by Nifi. Isn't it possible to restrict read access to anyone except Nifi? I'm wondering, because the common practice is to store sensitive information inside environment variables, while anyone who has access to OS can read them

Comment: Nifi-toolkit contains `encrypt-config.sh` script, still I haven't figure out yet if it'll help in this situation... https://www.contemplatingdata.com/2017/09/04/apache-nifi-encrypting-passwords-configuration-files/#:~:text=To%20encrypt%20nifi.,sensitive%20properties%20in%20the%20file.

Comment: finaly got it, Nifi encrypts values at rest https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#encrypt-config_tool.

Comment: encrypt-config doesn't apply to the variable files, only properties inside nifi.properties

Comment: parameter contexts have policies on them so you can set which users have read and write access to them, since variables are accessed through expression language there is no way to control it

Comment: wow, I didn't know encryption doesn't apply to variable files, thanks for that comment! Is that possible to do that on DEV env only DEV context can be chosen, and on PROD env - only PROD context?

Comment: after thinking a while I got that  Parameter Context doesn't solve one very important issue - changing parameter context requires a separate commit to Nifi Registry. I want to share Nifi Registry between environments, means I want to have a single commit that can be used on all environments

Comment: the idea is to have one param context like "my params", you create it in dev using values for dev, you commit to registry, then you import to prod, first time it creates the context for you, then you change the values to prod values, after that it only ever adds new params

Comment: i don't mean only one context, i just mean that whatever you named the context in dev, that is the same name in all environments, so you don't need to keep changing the context and commiting to registry

Comment: sorry, I am familiar with Context, but don't follow. I thought to have two contexts: "dev params" and "prod params" containing exactly the same keys but different values. So on deployment I was thinking about just switching contexts. Looks like having single context isn't enough

Comment: You have two nifi instances, dev and prod, they each have a context named "params"

Comment: does having Param Context with same name accross DEV and PROD mean that I will have two Nifi Registries: DEV and PROD? Otherwise, I don't understand how can I have two different environments with "param" Param Context

Comment: no you have one registry with one flow with one param context, the values of the param context in each nifi will be different, think of the param context as being local to each nifi, the stuff checked into registry is just a template of the required params to make the flow run, it has sensitive values removed and others have the initial value from dev that will be changed after you import to prod

Comment: thank you a lot!!! I finaly got it. Thank you very much, I didn't expect Param Context is local and isn't checked to Registry